# How can I remove the extra vertical space above and below this matrix?

Tags: matrices, boxes, bullets

I have written the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,fge,mathtools}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\setstacktabbedgap{2pt}
\setstackgap{L}{8pt}

\pagestyle{empty}

\author{}
\date{}
\title{}

\begin{document}

$\boxed{\Matrixstack{\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \cr \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \cr \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \cr \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \cr \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet}}$

\end{document}
```

which gives the following output:

[image]

but I don’t want that extra vertical space between the box and the bullets. How can I remove it?

Comment: Please note: This is not a *do it for me site*. So you should at least show, what you've already tried and where you failed. For such simple boxes and bullets you could simply use `\framebox`, `\bullet` and an `array` inside a math environment. Or you can use the native `picture` environment. Or you can use TikZ. Or you can use pstricks. …

Comment: There are several ways to do it, like A) using Tikz (pretty straight forward), B) using \fbox, \raisebox and wingding font, C) certainly you can use tables as well.

Comment: @cabohah I have edited my question according to your (fair) comment. I’d really like for it to be re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than you think.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\scatola}{mm}
 {% #1 = number of rows, #2 = number of columns
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
  \fbox{$\federico_scatola:nn { #1 } { #2 }$}
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \federico_scatola:nn
 {
  \begin{array}{*{#2}{c}}
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \bullet \prg_replicate:nn { #2 - 1 } { & \bullet } \\ }
  \end{array}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\scatola{1}{5}\times\scatola{1}{4} = \scatola{5}{4}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I add here the picture you wanted to reproduce in the original version of the question.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @egreg.

Answer (score 5):

For example with OpTeX:

```
\def\bbullets #1x#2 {%
   \frame{\vbox{\fornum 1..#2\do{\hbox{\fornum 1..#1\do{\mybullet}}}}}
}
\def\mybullet{\strut\kern.3em$\bullet$\kern.3em}

% test:
\bbullets 3x4

\bye
```

Comment: Thank you @wipet, but I’m not using optex unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

Try this simple format:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\fourbullets}{\bullet &\bullet &\bullet &\bullet}%
\newcommand{\fivebullets}{\bullet &\bullet &\bullet &\bullet &\bullet}%

$
\fbox{$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\fivebullets
\end{array}
$}
\times
\fbox{$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\fourbullets
\end{array}$
}=
\fbox{$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\fivebullets\\
\fivebullets\\
\fivebullets\\
\fivebullets\\
\fivebullets
\end{array}$
}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

But `wipet` already gave a best automated suggestion.